# Merge values of same keys in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a dataset something like the below.

```
[
    {-a: '-ess. (form feminine singular nouns.)'},
    {-a: '(form the feminine singular adjectives.)'},
    {-a: '(form the second-person singular.)'}, 
    {-aba: 'first-person singular'},
    {-aba: 'third-person singular'},
    ...
]
```

I want to have an object that has to be converted to the format of a single object, like the below.

```
{
    -a: '(form the second-person singular.)', 
    -aba: 'third-person singular', 
    ... 
}
```

The above is a result of `Object.assign({}, ...array)`.

But something is missing here, yep, some data has been trimmed accidentally from the original data above. This is not an desired result.

Now I have an obj that has a merged (in some way) value in the each key. The following is an example I would prefer.

```
{
    -a: '-ess. (form feminine singular nouns.)\n(form the feminine singular adjectives.)\n(form the second-person singular.)', 
    -aba: 'first-person singular\nthird-person singular', 
    ... 
}
```

So how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your data and then loop over each object to add them to the reduced value accordingly.

Also, your original array needs some `"`quotes`"` on the object keys, otherwise it won't run:

```js
const DATA = [
    {"-a": '-ess. (form feminine singular nouns.)'},
    {"-a": '(form the feminine singular adjectives.)'},
    {"-a": '(form the second-person singular.)'}, 
    {"-aba": 'first-person singular'},
    {"-aba": 'third-person singular'},
];

const merge = (data) => {
  // reduce the array down to a single object
  return data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // loop over the entries of each object
    Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // if this key already exists, append to it with \n
      if(acc[key] != null) {
        acc[key] += `\n${value}`;

      // else, just add it as is
      } else {
        acc[key] = value;
      }
    });
    
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(merge(DATA));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
const input = [
  { "-a": '-ess. (form feminine singular nouns.)' },
  { "-a": '(form the feminine singular adjectives.)' },
  { "-a": '(form the second-person singular.)' },
  { "-aba": 'first-person singular' },
  { "-aba": 'third-person singular' }
];

// option 1: store values in array
const output1 = input.reduce((outObj, item) => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];
  if (outObj[key]) {
    outObj[key].push(value);
  } else {
    outObj[key] = [value];
  }

  return outObj;
}, {});

console.log(output1);

// option 2: store values in a single string
function myFunc(arr, separator) {
  return arr.reduce((outObj, item) => {
    const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];
    if (outObj[key]) {
      outObj[key] += `${separator}${value}`;
    } else {
      outObj[key] = value;
    }

    return outObj;
  }, {});
}
const output2a = myFunc(input, '\n');
const output2b = myFunc(input, ' | ');

console.log(output2a);
console.log(output2b);
```